# C# interfacing between pc and Omron servopack sgdh

Tags: c#, interface, connection, drive, servo

I need help to write code c# interfacing between PC and Omron Servopack  by rs232 to USB connection [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcUA1.jpg)to drive ac servomotor

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific. Try adding some more details about what _exactly_ you need help with. The more specific you are, the better chance you have of getting some answer :)

Comment: I need to control servodrive (omron sgdh) by using program(c#) on computer by connection rs232 between servo drive  and computer.

Answer (score 0):

Using RS232 (CN3) to control this servo is not the best practice as it is not immune to EMC interference and is a port for driver setup (you will not be able to take graphics, and adjust the servo tuning while controlling through this port).

Consider researching the driver model you have and, if you have a fieldbus (Mecatrolink, DeviceNet, Profibus...), you could check how to use these protocols in a software (which I'll warn you, it's not trivial).

It all depends on your purpose, which could have been better explained in the question, as there are countless other approaches we can take...